# Hide a folder from USER only but not server

Tags: security, hide, directory

I'm looking for programs that will hide a folder from the user, but the PC will stil be able to access it.

For instance, I have a folder which has HTML files, so I want the program to hide it and not allow user to see it unless he gives a correct password, but if I will access the folder from any browser inorder to see that content(the website), it will work.

Actually, the functionality is similiar to Windows hidden folders which you can set by clicking on the right mouse button -> properties -> hide ->apply, but I also want that inorder to unhide it and view it, you will have to supply a password.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a programming question if you are looking for an existing prewritten program.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Set up a special user to access those files and run your web server in
  that same porifle.
- Use a Third party software: http://www.pcworld.com/article/230946/Passwords.html